# Marshalling a Pointer to Array of Structs

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, struct, marshalling

I am trying to invoke a driver dll for a force sensor thats been written for c/cpp. The working Cpp code looks like this:

I the header file that was delivered with the dll, the struct is defined like this

```
typedef struct
{
  DWORD usb_hid_idx;
  int open;
  char vid_pid[256];
  char dev_info[256];
  char sn_info[256];
  int hw_info;
  unsigned char hw_var;
  int fw_vers;
} t_DeviceInfo;
```

And the function I need to call is defined like this:

```
extern "C" DLL_API int Search(t_DeviceInfo *p_dev_info);
```

In the main code I just create an array of the former defined `t_DeviceInfo`struct and a pointer to the first element and call the function `Search`with this pointer:

```
t_DeviceInfo deviceInfo[16];
t_DeviceInfo* deviceInfoPtr = &deviceInfo[0];
int ret = search(deviceInfoPtr);
```

At least there, everything works fine. With C# it currently looks like this:

```
unsafe public struct t_DeviceInfo
{
    long usb_hid_idx;
    int open;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    char[] vid_pid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    char[] dev_info;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    char[] sn_info;
    int hw_info;
    char hw_var;
    int fw_vers;
}

unsafe public class ASTAS
{
    [DllImport("ASTAS_DLL.dll")]
    public extern static int Search(t_DeviceInfo* devInfPtr);
}
```

And in the main:

```
t_DeviceInfo[] devInfo = new t_DeviceInfo[16];
```

But thats about it. How do I marshal the array of structs to a fixed memory location and pass the corresponding pointer to `Search()`?

Comment: You should add `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` to your structure.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Since that is the default for `struct`, how would that change anything?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The default is `LayoutKind.Auto` ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind(v=vs.110).aspx)), and my comment didn't mean to solve the question by itself.

Comment: @Lucas on a struct, when you omit the StructLayout attribute, you get sequential layout. For a class you get auto.

Comment: @David Hmm... you may be right, but I can't find any doc on MSDN for this behavior so I wouldn't rely on it. And IMHO the attribute is a nice indicator that says "this struct is used in interop, don't mess with it".

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I cannot find any docs that state that either

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for `unsafe` here. You may as well remove that. And your struct declaration is incorrect. Some of the types are wrong. An C++ `DWORD` is a unsigned 32 bit value. A C# `long` is a signed 64 bit value. A C++ `unsigned char` is an unsigned 8 bit value. A C# char is a 16 bit character. Typically `unsigned char` maps to `byte`.

The struct should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct t_DeviceInfo
{
    uint usb_hid_idx;
    int open;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string vid_pid;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string dev_info;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    string sn_info;
    int hw_info;
    byte hw_var;
    int fw_vers;
}
```

The function declaration should then be:

```
[DllImport("ASTAS_DLL.dll")]
public extern static int Search([In] t_DeviceInfo[] devInfPtr);
```

This assumes that the calling convention is stdcall. It looks to me as though it is actually cdecl. In which case you need:

```
[DllImport("ASTAS_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static int Search([In] t_DeviceInfo[] devInf);
```

I've used `[In]` marshalling. You may need to modify that depending on the semantics, which I cannot discern from the information provided.

Comment: Hi and thansk for the suggestion :)

Comment: I tried the cdecl calling convention and Search gives back an error and doesn't attempt to write to the struct array. 'Thiscall' seems to work, but I get an access violation. StdCall also seems to work, but I get a stack imbalance error.

Comment: What is `DLL_API`? Evidence suggests that `cdecl` is the correct choice. It won't be `thiscall` because this is not an instance method. So, it would seem that `cdecl` is the choice, and you need to work out how to call the function properly. If you want to see anything returned in the array, then you need `[In, Out]` or `[Out]`. Remember that you've told us nothing about how to call the function and which way the data flows. Only you know that.

Comment: Hi, my testing suggests, that cdecl is ok as calling convetion for a bunch of other functions in this dll so it should also be ok for Search(). But on the other hand, every other function also is called correctly with StdCall. And I dont know, what DLL_API is doing - I kind of hoped you would ^^

Comment: Is there any way to look at a stack content during runtime or at a breakpoint? Maybe by looking at the actual output from Search() to the buffer I can figure out if the buffer is initialized correctly.

Comment: Nope. Only you can say what `DLL_API` is. It's defined in your header file. And as to how to call the function, again only you know that because you didn't give any details of that. I don't think we can do much more than what's in my answer.

Comment: Hi, actually, your answer was totally correct - the function has to be called by Cdecl. Thanks for the help :) Regarding `DLL_API`: I found it in the header file to be defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`depending on if a define `DLLEXPORT`was defined or not... But I am afraid I don't understand that part very well.

Comment: That's a standard idiom. It allows the header file to be used both when building the DLL (`dllexport`) and using the DLL (`dllimport`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`fixed` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) in an [`unsafe` context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx).